# (Reference Request) Canonical forms for Real and Complex binary forms of low degree.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, lie-groups

I am asking for a reference for Canonical forms for Real (and Complex) binary forms of low degree with respect to the natural action of the Real (and Complex) special linear group $SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ (respectively $SL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$).

Advanced thanks for any help.